# How to sort a grouped bar-chart d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this **[block](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/d73ef3eb17287b30a87290cce57e2d98)** **(FIXED)** I've tried to do a sorting function in a similar fashion to **[this](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b)**.

It technically sorts the bars but not in the expected way, if you check the sorting checkbox and shift years you can see what I mean.

I thought that it had something to do with the fact that it's only sorting based on `data` and not `keys` and/or the `copy` variable but I've tried sorting in all kinds of ways based on the mentioned variables without any success.

Not sure what I'm missing, appreciate any help!

Comment: Seems like you are sorting by the "total" value and according to that, the bars seem correct. Do you want the bars for every group sorted as well based on their values?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the bars are technically sorting but not in the way that it does in the other example. The bars don't shift x-position when you update the data (and toggle the sorting checkbox) like they do [here](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b) if you toggle the checkbox and update the data.

As for your question, no, only interested in sorting by total value in each group, as it does. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Yes @Robert! I got it. My bad. I'll add a link with a solution asap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! There was not much change required in your previous code.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yRQQ7T?p=preview)

So this was related to the data binding to the barGroups. Every time the data was sorted or changed, new data was bound to the "g.layer" and with d3's update methodology, this would how it would work.

Changes in the new code:

- Moved barGroups code above the data sorting with no transform attribute.
- Added transform attribute to the groups after x0 domain is defined.

Relevant code:

Above the sort function:

```
// bars
let barGroups = g.selectAll("g.layer").data(data);
barGroups.enter().append("g")
  .classed('layer', true);

barGroups.exit().remove();
```

Once x0 domain is set:

```
g.selectAll("g.layer").transition().duration(Globalvar.durations)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)";
  });
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the explanation as well.