# Sorting a stacked bar chart d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In this **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iNi8b9XlYUb4CVRCnrRf?p=preview)** I have the same problem as I had in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818419/how-to-sort-a-grouped-bar-chart-d3js-v4) where my `data.sort` function is technically sorting the bars as they should but not in the desired way.

Just like last time, I'd like em to be sorting like **[this](https://bl.ocks.org/LemoNode/73dbb9d6a144476565386f48a2df2e3b)** rather than the way they're sorting now.

I've tried putting the `data.sort` alongside the `x.domain` and `axis--x` in various ways without any success and I'm all out of ideas.

Any help is as always appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to have them sorted? Can you explain it instead of linking? I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want the x-axis values (the stacked bars) to shift x-position rather than update the data as they do now when they are sorted. Like in the last link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yWy54UC60uNkt3xsLvxZ?p=preview)

You need to use key functions `.data(d=>d,d=>d.data.State);`, so that d3 knows which data is new, old, or existing. It's recommended to always use key functions, unless you want the data to be keyed by array index.

You also need to apply the `x` transformation to the existing bars.

Even though your example doesn't have new data after the initial data, it's still good practice to merge the `enter` selection with the `update` selection, and then run the transition.

```
let bars = g.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
      .data(d=>d,d=>d.data.State);

  bars = bars.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth()).merge(bars)
    .transition().duration(Globalvar.durations)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.State); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); });
```

notice how the merge code is more concise than writing the transition twice for both the `enter` and `update` selections.

```
let bars = g.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d; });

bars.enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .transition().duration(Globalvar.durations)
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.State); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); });

  bars.transition().duration(Globalvar.durations)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll accept it since it answered my question, but it messed up the category update function (it redraws from top left rather than update the existing rect), I'll post another question if I can't fix it myself though, thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, i've updated the plunker to fix it. Feel free to try to fix it on your own first.